# Does any Windows based screen capture handle at least 720p at 60 FPS?

Tags: screen-capture

I tried MANY programs for screen capturing, but I simply cannot get over 20 FPS at 720p.

I tried CamStudio, which is very recommended over internet, but its not close enought. Whats interesting is, when I am recording something using it, I get low FPS, but my CPU usage is on barely 20%. On most used core. I just dont get it. I am sure I set everything fine. So why isnt CamStudio using at least one of my cores at 100% ? I have Core i5 4 physical cores at 4 GHz. In addition I have 4GB of 1600MHz DDR3 RAM and ma ysystem use SSD drive. This setup MUST be able to capture even full HD in more than 30 FPS. Please, do you know about any program that could do it? I can record with FRAPS games at my native 1680x1050, even demanding like Bad Company 2 on HIGH setting and still get 30FPS video with enought power left for 50 FPS at game. And from what I know, Windows 7 desktop runs as D3D. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, one to get quite good fps is [Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia). I use an old version given away by a computer magazine, in a DVD. The company used to give away older versions for magazines, now I don't know. I have been able to capture 60fps with no issues 1024x768, and 1280x800. So, not exactly 720p but very similar. Using an i5 650, 4ghz, with a way worse card than you have (now that I remember, have captured no issue 60fps with a pentium 4). Beware is not all about that hardware. Is probably way more important that disk is fast, and it is defragmented. If your windows is unstable, or have memory problems, that's going to be an issue, though. The key for hickups tends to be memory/disk.

I have, even with Camtasia, noticed a better performance setting Windows fully to the resolution, or close, in which vid is to be captured. IE, setting desktop at 1024x768, so no window/region capture, but simply full screen capture, video output being then 1024x768.

Anyway, there are settings you'd better tweak in preferences.

If you can not purchase any old magazine issue + CD, for the Camtasia thing, I have been experimenting with a jewell for capturing ingame shots, but it seems to capture anything. And it's free, and showing amazing performance: [Gregion](http://www.gregion.com/game/manual/64.html) . Was the only one allowing me great capture at high fps, of complex experiment I was making.

Of course, if all this fails, you still have the option to download Camtasia trial, see if works for you, and then purchase it...

EDIT: The reason why fraps might be capturing better, is because surely those capturers do leave it more for the 3d card, and usage of direct3d/opengl is being way more optimized in a game, than in a general usage system desktop. Sounds like the card is making most of the job.

Comment: I have the current version and I love it...Camtasia realy is the king. they do have a free alternative to camtasia called [Jing](http://www.techsmith.com/jing/)

Comment: Hey, was not aware about Jing, thanks! Seems I am not going to need it, but prefer to know about these things :)

Comment: 720p is 1280x720.

Comment: Interesting, had never heard of Gregion before

Answer (score 0):

You should download SCREEN2SWF. It records up to 30FPS it has a built-in editor and it's easy to use. You can pause/play start/stop recordings. It supports windows. (I'm not sure about mac. I have windows 10 you can check yourself) SCREEN2SWF was no where seen in suggestions in other websites. I searched up '30 fps screen recorders' and saw that.

I hope this helps anyone in 2016

Answer (score 0):

As S.gfx has mentioned, Camtasia is really good.

- I've had my desktop recordings 1920x1080(my desktop resolution) at 60fps!
- plus you will have a lightweight video editor along with the recorder
- but you might wanna compress the output video coz sometimes it gets huge. This is because it records video with little or no compression and in '.avi' format.

Comment: This is really commentary about another answer.  In this Q&A format, each answer should contribute another solution to the question.  With a little more rep, you will be able to comment.